# How To add a placeholder to jQuery Tokeninput?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

How can I add a placeholder to a jQuery Tokeninput field? A normal `placeholder` attribute won't work in here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the current version of `tokenInput` supports this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#elementID").tokenInput("http://www.foo.com/bar", {
  placeholder: 'Place holder text...'
});
```

Comment: There is no placeholder setting I found in tokenInput doc

Answer (score 7):

For a input like:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

You can do:

```
$("#myInput").tokenInput("/scripts/myjson.js");
$("#token-input-myInput").attr("placeholder", "Type here");
```

When you use tokenInput, it changes your input's id to "token-input-XXX", where XXX is the previous id