# Add place holder text to Jquery Tokeninput

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I tried the solution mentioned here [How To add a placeholder to jQuery Tokeninput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876286/how-to-add-a-placeholder-to-jquery-tokeninput) but its not working.Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to add default text in text fields using Tokeninput?

Answer (score 2):

The `placeholder` option was only added in v1.6.1, it's not available in v1.6.0 which is the verison the website prompts you to download.

Download the latest version from [Github](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput).

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect if you use old version of tokeninput. tokeninput 1.7 is out now:
https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/releases/tag/v1.7.0

Using placeholder in tokeninput:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tokeninput_1").tokenInput("<address your script>", {
    ...
    placeholder: 'your placeholder text ...'
});
```